# Publishing an private android app

Tags: android, private, publish

I've done an app to a company and I have to decide de way to share it out.
And I'm wondering if there's some way to publish it on PlayStore but in some private way, I mean, that does'nt be visible until you write down the name of the app to download it...
So, if I want that the users of the company don't have to change permissions of their android to allow apps from not trusty locations, what would be the best or the differents ways to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a **specific code issue**.

Comment: ... it also is a duplicate of many questions here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the various [distribution](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html) ways google listed on their site.

You probably want to distribute via Email or through your company's website.